# Problem in reading incoming data from serialport using NodeJS serialport package

Tags: javascript, node.js, node-serialport

I am trying to read data coming from Silicon Labs CP210x USB device using SerialPort package of NodeJS. Following is the code I am using.

```
    var SerialPort = require('serialport');
    var port = new SerialPort('COM1', {
    baudRate: 9600,
    parity: 'none',
    stopBits: 1,
    dataBits: 8,
    flowControl: false
    });

    port.on('open', function(){
    console.log('yes port is open');
    });

    port.on('data', function (data) {
    console.log('Data: ' + data);
    });
```

on port 'open' the function is running fine. But during on 'data', the function not triggers. Even I have used the parser ReadLine method, nothing happens. Please help me.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried logging out any errors that occur?

```
port.on('error', function (err) {
    console.log(err);
    return;
});
```

Answer (score 0):

'COM1' is not allowed as this number was reserved for the SUB-D9 RS232 hardware. Assuming you're running on WINDOWS, open the configuration panel, find your serialport COM number and replace COM1 by the one you found.